# Real time video streaming (from cameras on arm board) over Ethernet using Server-Client Communication

Tags: video-streaming, client-server, embedded-linux

I am new to embedded linux programming. I am working on arm cortex A15 which is integrated with IMI Gen4 minicube automotive cameras. Now I need to get the real time video captured by camera on to my local host machine (based on linux).

Server side:

```
int main(void)
{
    int listenfd = 0;
    int connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr,client;
    char sendBuff[];
    int numrv;

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    printf("Socket retrieve success\n");

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));

    if(listen(listenfd, 10) == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to listen\n");
        return -1;
    }


    while(1)
    {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*) &client ,sizeof(client));

        /* Open the file that we wish to transfer */
        FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/video0","rb");
        if(fp==NULL)
        {
            printf("File opern error");
            return 1;   
        }   

        /* Read data from file and send it */
        while(1)
        {
            /* First read file in chunks of 256 bytes */
            unsigned char buff[256]={0};
            int nread = fread(buff,1,256,fp);
            printf("Bytes read %d \n", nread);        

            /* If read was success, send data. */
            if(nread > 0)
            {
                printf("Sending \n");
                write(connfd, buff, nread);
            }

            /*
             * There is something tricky going on with read .. 
             * Either there was error, or we reached end of file.
             */
            if (nread < 256)
            {
                if (feof(fp))
                    printf("End of file\n");
                if (ferror(fp))
                    printf("Error reading\n");
                break;
            }


        }

        close(connfd);
        sleep(1);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Client side:

```
int main(void)
{
    int sockfd = 0;
    int bytesReceived = 0;
    char recvBuff[256];
    memset(recvBuff, '0', sizeof(recvBuff));
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    /* Create a socket first */
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Initialize sockaddr_in data structure */
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); // port
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    /* Attempt a connection */
    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Create file where data will be stored */
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("video.txt", "ab"); 
    if(NULL == fp)
    {
        printf("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Receive data in chunks of 256 bytes */
    while((bytesReceived = read(sockfd, recvBuff, 256)) > 0)
    {
        printf("Bytes received %d\n",bytesReceived);    
        // recvBuff[n] = 0;
        fwrite(recvBuff, 1,bytesReceived,fp);
        // printf("%s \n", recvBuff);
    }

    if(bytesReceived < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Read Error \n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I tried running the server code on arm side and client on my local host side. But I am getting error with reading `/dev/video0` file  `printf("Error reading\n")`. Is this not the right file that is getting updated with real time video captured by camera. If not this then please give me an idea on how to stream a video on Ethernet.

Comment: Improved question a little

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you are trying to read /dev/video0 like that. /dev/video0 is neither a regular file, nor a regular char device. Instead, it's a video4linux device, and as such exposes a well-known API, which is very well [documented](https://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/v4l2spec.html).

I'd suggest to try to leverage some higher level framework, such as gstreamer to stream the video from a server. There are plenty of documentation about gstreamer and about how to do this.

You should first get familiar with video4linux, and then get familiar with gstreamer. A good exercise is to stream a camera on a laptop, before doing it in the embedded platform.